# Convert COBOL ICI Date format 9 Digit Number to Date

Tags: date, cobol

I am working on converting a COBOL based Data transformation into Informatica BDM. One of the field in COBOL file is a ICI Date format which is a 9 Digit Number and it has to be converted into a standard date.
Example 336005121 = 01 Aug 2007.

Please let me know if anyone has come across this issue.

Appreciate your help.

Comment: After a brief online search, I did not find any description of the "ICI" date format.  Can you provide us any additional information about this format -- for instance, what is "ICI" short for?

Comment: Is it something to do with [iPath Optimized Currency Carry ETN](https://money.usnews.com/funds/etfs/multicurrency/ipath-optimized-currency-carry-etn/ici)?